# Internationalisation Issue in CSV File

Tags: laravel, unicode, laravel-4, internationalization, maatwebsite-excel

I am working on a website using Laravel 4.2. There are some characters like `é` saved in database, retrieved and looks fine on the webpages, but when these characters are exported in a CSV files and are opened in Microsoft Excel 2013 on Windows 10 or Libre 5 on Ubuntu 15.10 it is converted into `Ã©` etc.

I'm using Maatwebsite to Export CSV files for Laravel 4.2. Can anyone please help me how to solve this issue.

Answer (score -1):

`Ã©` is what you see when `é` is decoded with the encoding such as `latin1` or `Windows-1252` instead of UTF-8.

Excel expects a byte order mark (BOM, U+FEFF) in a CSV file or will assume ANSI encoding, which is locale dependent (`Windows-1251` on US Windows, for example).  Find a converter or save option to save in UTF-8 with BOM.  Notepad++ can convert encodings, for example.